# Vim: Seeing *all* lines change when inserting to a visual block

Tags: vim, gvim

When I Insert text before a visual block ('I') I only see the first line of the block change. After hitting esc, the rest of the lines change accordingly.

Is there a way to have all lines change as I type?

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry, but I'm fairly certain that you have to leave insert mode (press escape) to see the changes apply across all the lines in the visual block.