# VIM prepend lines using visual block

Tags: vim

Trying to prepend a # to all lines in a visual block by highlighting, I (shift - i) but only the first line changes (even after hitting esc)

This is the method I've found in a number of places including 
[Vim: Seeing *all* lines change when inserting to a visual block](https://superuser.com/questions/201383/vim-seeing-all-lines-change-when-inserting-to-a-visual-block)

but it doesnt work for me.  Do I need to change a setting or could I be doing something incorrectly?

edit: if it matters, GVIM on windows.

Comment: I experience the same behaviour on linux ubuntu, since the last upgrade to 14.10. I dont have any weird windows like settings but the behaviour is the same, also if I prepend somethign else than # it works, but slow, i have to wait liek 3 seconds and if in this time i use arrows - the operation fails, only first line is prepended. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Enter *VISUAL-BLOCK* mode with `<C-v>`.
2. Select all the lines you want to comment.
3. Type `I#` to prepend the first line with `#` then hit `<Esc>` to exit *VISUAL-BLOCK* mode and apply your change to all the lines.

I think some people use GVim on Windows with a weird setting that makes its keyboard shortcuts more "Windows-like". If that's your case `<C-v>` might not work, try `<C-q>` instead.

- `:help visual-block`
- `:help ctrl-v-alternative`
- `:help v-b-i`

You can obtain the same result without the benefit of a "preview" using the `:normal` command (`:help normal`):

1. Enter *VISUAL-LINE* mode with `<S-v>`
2. Select all the lines you want to comment.
3. Type `:normal I#` then hit `<CR>` to apply your change to all the lines.